# use jQuery to replace a CSS stylesheet if body class changes

Tags: jquery, css, replace, stylesheet

I have a stylesheet in my head as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/jooswatch-v3-5/css/bootswatch/superhero/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I am trying to replace the above stylesheet with the follow ones if the body#main.whatever class changes (on different pages for example).

i.e.

changing from:
*body#main.itemid113*

to:
*body#main.itemid114*

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   $('body#main.itemid113').replaceWith('<link rel="stylesheet" id="main" href="/templates/jooswatch-v3-5/css/bootswatch/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />');

   $('body#main.itemid114').replaceWith('<link rel="stylesheet" id="main" href="/templates/jooswatch-v3-5/css/bootswatch/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />');

});
</script>
```

How would I do this - the above is not working.

Would this be correct?

```
jQuery(function($){
    if ($('.itemid113').length){
        $('body').append("<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/jooswatch-v3-5/css/bootswatch/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />");
    };
    if ($('.itemid114').length){
        $('body').append("<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/jooswatch-v3-5/css/bootswatch/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css");
    }
});
```

Comment: The second wouldn't be correct? You have to replace some quotes. And if you want to replace a stylesheet, you need to remove the original one or replace it ;)

Comment: so how would I do that?

Comment: Well, I don't know what stylesheet you want to replace but you could try something like `$('link#whateverid').replaceWith('<link rel="stylesheet"..../>')`

Comment: Have I not done that already above with my second bit of code?

Comment: Are you stylesheets in the `body` tag? Try putting a space between `body` and `#main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to add an id to your link tag i.e.:

```
<link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/jooswatch-v3-5/css/bootswatch/superhero/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Then your script becomes:

```
jQuery(function($){
    if ($('.itemid113').length){
        $('#theme').attr("href","/templates/jooswatch-v3-5/css/bootswatch/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css");
    };
    if ($('.itemid114').length){
        $('#theme').attr("href", "/templates/jooswatch-v3-5/css/bootswatch/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css");
    }
});
```